# Loading images with Parse in GridView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make an application which grabs all the ParseFiles in a ParseObject and display them in a GridView, successively.

I've done so with one activity, which represents a news feed, and everything works fine.

But when I'm trying to implement the same method in my other activity, it doesn't work.

I'm using an AsyncTask to load the images in the background.

This is my code:

**ThumbnailItems.java (POJO class)**

```
public class ThumbnailItems {
    Bitmap thumb;
    // Empty constructor.
    public ThumbnailItems(){

    }
    // Constructor.
    public ThumbnailItems(Bitmap thumb){
        super();
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }
    // Getter.
    public Bitmap getImage(){
        return thumb;
    }
    // Setter.
    public void setImage(Bitmap thumb){
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }
}
```

**My AsyncTask:**

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        thumbItemsList = new ArrayList<ThumbnailItems>();
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> postQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Posts");

            postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            objectList = postQuery.find();
            for (ParseObject posts : objectList){

                final ThumbnailItems thumbItems = new ThumbnailItems();
                // Locate user profile picture.
                ParseFile thumbFile = (ParseFile) posts.get("author_img");
                thumbFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Bitmap userImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length)
                                    , 150, 150, false);
                            thumbItems.setImage(userImage);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("ParseException", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thumbItemsList.add(thumbItems);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e){
            Log.e("ParseException", "Error: " + e.getMessage() + " with code: " + e.getCode());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, null, false);
        gridView = (GridView) activityView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext()
                , R.layout.profile_viewpager_tab1_children
                , thumbItemsList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

(I've already seen [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-gridview-tutorial/) tutorial, but I really want to be consistent with my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think batter to use Like.
and don't use AsyncTask to load the images in the background.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "ClassName");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e == null) {
                    // hear u will get responce.
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : list) {
                        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject.get(""); // hear
                                                                            // set
                                                                            // column
                                                                            // name
                                                                            // same
                                                                            // as
                                                                            // parse
                                                                            // table
                        if (image != null) {
                            // hear store image into your custom array.
                            // Like...
                            Log.e("get Image ",
                                    " IMAGE URL IS " + image.getUrl());
                        }
                    }

                    // and hear u can set your adapter
                    // and yr grid view
                    // in adapter to use Picasso libary for image shower.
                    // how to use picasso lib.
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("image url")
                            .fit().into(imageview);
                } else {
                    // hear is yr fail responce
                    // e.getMessage()
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. I implemented this and it worked like a charm!

Comment: This is a bad solution. 
This will cause the adapter to call this background method everytime user scrolls and this will cause lag in the performance. You probably will experience that your recycle view is not smooth.